# Unable to unzip .gz file in terminal - file.gz: not in gzip format

Tags: linux, compression, tar, gzip

I have a  db.tar.gz file (approx 500mb) and I am using the vagrant (unix) terminal to decompress the file.

Using the following [instructions](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-decompress-files-in-gzip.html) here I am using gunzip to attempt decompression of the file using the command below but have problems (shown below)

`gunzip < db.tar.gz | tar xvf -`

// This command gives me the following output in the terminal

`gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Used unix `file` function to check file itself & I get the following output in the terminal.
`file db.tar.gz`

Can anyone explain why I am getting this issue with the db.tar.gz file how can I rectify it (its an mysql dump)
`db.tar.gz UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines`

Comment: Despite the name, it's not a gzip compressed file, it's plain text. Not even in tar format, based on that `file` output.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with only

```
    tar xvf db.tar.gz
```

If not, try it